# When was the first OP_RETURN output in a coinbase?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, op-return, soft-fork, bip-34, bip-30

One way to deal with the *[BIP34](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0034) does not imply [BIP30](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0030)* issue, aka the [Block 1,983,702 Problem](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/120834/what-is-the-block-1-983-702-problem), is a soft-fork that makes the SegWit commitment mandatory. [0]

There are no `OP_RETURN` outputs in any of the coinbase transactions before BIP34 activated (unless my script is wrong [1]), let alone `OP_RETURN` outputs starting with the SegWit magic bytes `0x6a24aa21a9ed.`

Nowadays `OP_RETURN` outputs in the coinbase transaction are very common, used not just for the SegWit commitment, but also by sidechain(ish) protocols.

When was the first instance of this?

[0] https://twitter.com/kcalvinalvinn/status/1733008287887659266

[1] https://gist.github.com/Sjors/018f764b28efdf29fda60e47f19615a5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first coinbase transaction that has an OP_RETURN output is in block [246816](https://mempool.space/block/000000000000000a6913ee4ada3b92bed9f1398ad8f22f4f944a5d5593197d68). The transaction has 288 outputs in total, and the OP_RETURN is the last one.

Comment: Thanks! How did you find it?

Comment: I wrote a script that goes through every block in order until it finds one whose coinbase transaction has an output whose output script starts with the byte `6a`.